# The ? matcher vs pattern| empty

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been practicing regex's and came across this question.

Match:

- battle axe
- splitting axe
- pickaxe

I came to a solution using:

```
(battle|splitting|pick)(\s|)axe
```

The suggested solution is:

```
(battle|splitting|pick)\s?axe
```

In my original solution, how is the "OR" operator working? When I run the standard OR operator in javascript without two expressions, it throws an error.

Is:

```
(pattern|)
```

equivalent to:

```
pattern?
```

How is `(pattern|)` working in my first solution?

Comment: Aside from answering your question, the suggested solution is pretty puzzling, since it matches "battleaxe" "splittingaxe" and "pick axe" as well. I think `(battle\s|splitting\s|pick)axe` is preferable.

Comment: Other solution to puzzle are `/[\w]+[ ]?axe/g`, `/.+[ ]?axe/m`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my original solution, how is the "OR" operator working? When I run the standard OR operator in javascript without two expressions, it throws an error.

A regex operator is not a JS operator like `||`. The empty string is a valid regular expression, and can serve as an operand to the [Alternation operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

> Is `(pattern|)` equivalent to `pattern?`

Not exactly, there's an additional [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) in the first one. But they work the same in regard to the matched language, yes.

Comment: Note that if `pattern` contains more than one characters ex. `(abc|)` is not equivalent to `abc?`.

Comment: That's why I put the *`pattern`* in italics - it needs to be a single [Alternative](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-alternative) expression in the first and an [Atom](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-term) even in the second, yes.

Comment: @DmitryYaremenko Since `?` is after `c` and it's not inside a character set or something else, only `c` is optional. So it matches both "ab" and "abc"

Comment: @noob Yes, I meant it